# How to remove rollover color in Link Button in flex 2

Tags: apache-flex, styles, flex2

How do I remove the rollover background,selection color from link button in flex 2.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by setting upSkin, downSkin and overSkin to null using setStyle method.

```
 linkButton.setStyle('upSkin', null);
 linkButton.setStyle('overSkin', null);
 linkButton.setStyle('downSkin', null);
```

The above disables the selectionColor,rollOverColor from Link button.

Comment: Please make sure you mark your own answer as correct when you are able to (should be after 2 days, I believe)